# How to Get Header Info from Wav Stored in MemoryStream?

Tags: c#, save, wav

I have a memory stream that contains a wave file.

The wav can be played like this:

```
var soundPlayer = new System.Media.SoundPlayer();
soundPlayer.Stream = stream;
soundPlayer.Play();
```

How do I extract bitrate, sampling rates, channel, etc from stream?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The header size is like 36 bytes or so.
So you can create a buffer and read it like this

```
byte[] headers = byte[36];
memorystream.Position = 0;
memorystream.Read(headers,0,headers.Length);
/** doing your meta data extraction **/
 String mode;
 if(headers[22] ==  1)
    mode = "mono";
 else if(headers[22] == 2)
    mode = "stereo";
 else 
    mode = "unknown";
/*************************************/
memorystream.Position = 0;
```

Check following links for headers info:

- http://www-mmsp.ece.mcgill.ca/documents/audioformats/wave/wave.html
- http://soundfile.sapp.org/doc/WaveFormat/

Hope it helps. :-)